# How to Handel exception during Mysql connection

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I m trying to connect to a mysql database. if server is not responding, my application crashes. I am using try, except but looks like two exceptions are raising and "try: except" could not handle it. can some one figure it out where is the problem. below is my code:-

```
def check_server(server_address):

    con = mysql.connector.connect(host='{}'.format(server_address),
                                  database='domicile_reports',
                                  user='xyz',
                                  password='xyz')

    try:

        if con.is_connected():
            print('{} Connected'.format(server_address))
            con.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Can not connect to db. {} Occured".format(e)) 
 check_server('25.13.253.67')
```

Error displayed on terminal:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hamid Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector
network.py", line 574, in open_connection
self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "f:\Docs\OneDrive\Python Projects\CFC App\splash_screen_gui.py", line 151, in 
obj = splashscreen()
File "f:\Docs\OneDrive\Python Projects\CFC App\splash_screen_gui.py", line 51, in **init**
self.check_server(self.server_2)
File "f:\Docs\OneDrive\Python Projects\CFC App\splash_screen_gui.py", line 80, in check_server
con = mysql.connector.connect(host='{}'.format(server_address),
File "C:\Users\Hamid Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector_*init*_.py", line 273, in connect
return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Hamid Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 116, in **init**
self.connect(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Hamid Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1052, in connect
self._open_connection()
File "C:\Users\Hamid Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 494, in _open_connection
self._socket.open_connection()
File "C:\Users\Hamid Shah\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 576, in open_connection
raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '25.13.253.67:3306' (10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
respond)

Comment: There are many possible reasons for this error. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html for a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `connect()` call inside the `try: except` block. You can also use a context manager to properly close the connection, example:

```
import mysql.connector

from mysql.connector.errors import Error


def check_server(server_address):
    try:
        with mysql.connector.connect(
            host=server_address,
            database="domicile_reports",
            user="xyz",
            password="xyz",
        ) as cnx:
            print(f"{server_address} Connected")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Can not connect to db. {err} Occured")


check_server("25.13.253.67")
```